# How to allow horizontal scroll in for background image?

Tags: html, css

I am working on simple creative where i want to scroll background image of div horizontally when cursor drag left or right.

So basically i have div of width 300px which have background image greater than div width. now whenever you drag or swipe image should move accordingly

Here is code:

```
<style>
.sprite-container {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    background-image: url("sprite.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}
</style>
<div class="sprite-container"></div>
```

Here is jsfiddle link for same : http://jsfiddle.net/janakprajapati90/gzLqspar/

Comment: can you show me exactly what you want? because you may not want what comes to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `calc()` together with saving the position on clicking. Then calculate the difference on the mouse move.

```js
const vertical_scroll = false;
const horizontal_scroll = true;

(function(){
  const scrolls = document.querySelectorAll(".sprite-container");
  for(let i = 0; i < scrolls.length; i++){
    initScrollable(scrolls.item(i), vertical_scroll, horizontal_scroll);
  }
})();

function initScrollable(t, vertical_scroll, horizontal_scroll){
  const init_bg_pos = [
    getComputedStyle(t, null)["background-position-x"],
    getComputedStyle(t, null)["background-position-y"]
  ];

  let dragging = false;
  let coords = [];
  let offset = [0, 0];

  t.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    dragging = true;
    coords = [e.offsetX - offset[0], e.offsetY - offset[1]];
  });

  t.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    dragging = false;
  });

  t.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    if(dragging){
      offset = [e.offsetX - coords[0], e.offsetY - coords[1]];

      t.style.backgroundPosition = 
        (horizontal_scroll ? (
            "calc(" + init_bg_pos[0] + " + " + offset[0] + "px)"
        ) : (
            init_bg_pos[0]
        )) + 
        " " + 
        (vertical_scroll ? (
          "calc(" + init_bg_pos[1] + " + " + offset[1] + "px)"
        ) : (
          init_bg_pos[1]
        ));
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.sprite-container {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("http://codeclippers.xyz/sprite.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment:scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i wanted to achive it using css and vanilla javascript only.

Comment: You can do the same in vanilla javascript too. If you need it I can modify my answer. PS: You should add that to your question the next time ;)

Comment: @JanakPrajapati Ok, I converted everything to vanilla javascript :)

Comment: Hey man, i tried this solution basically it works on browser but in case off SDK scrolling is not working
Basically i have created native ad and integrated it with mopub sdk
if you have time have look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192191/how-to-scroll-image-horizontally-inside-fixed-container-using-javascript-in-touc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure using `background-image` here is what you want.
What about that:

```css
.img-container{
  width: 300px;
  /*height: 200px;*/ /* Probably not needed */
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://codeclippers.xyz/sprite.png">
</div>
```

Quoting [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp):

> The `background-attachment` property sets whether a background image scrolls with the rest of the page, or is fixed.

It doesn't allow you to scroll the div if there's no content overflowing it.