# How to scroll image horizontally inside fixed container using javascript in touch devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on solution where i have fixed width container with image having width more than container

What i want to achive is in touch devices whenever user swipe on that particular image it should display accordingly.

Here is my code:

```
html,body {
    font-family:Open Sans;
}
.ad300x250_container {
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.img-container{
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.ad300x250_action button {
    background: #058562;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #058562;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:700;
    font-family: open sans;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align:center;
    width:80%;
    padding:5px 15px;
    width:130px;
    position:absolute;
    top:165px;
    left:80px;  
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #999;    
}

.ad_native_container {
        float:left;
        height:50px;
    }
    .ad300x250_icon {
        float: left;
        width: 42px;
        height: 50px
    }
    .ad300x250_icon img {
        width: 42px;
        height: 42px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: 1px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
    .ad300x250_title_container {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .ad300x250_title {
        font-family: open sans;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #000;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        line-height: 14px;
        padding-top: 6px
    }

    .ad300x250_action_container {
        float: left
    }

    .ad300x250_description {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
        margin-top:5px;
    }

    .ad300x250_description_text {
        font-family: open sans;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #666;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;

    }

    .ad300x250_action_container button {
        height: 27px;
        background: #058562;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #fff;
        border-color: #058562;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: open sans;
        border-style: solid;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 11px;
        display: flex;
        padding: 2px 15px
    }
    .ad300x250_description_rating {
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .ad_media_container {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .scroll-touch {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Lets it scroll lazy */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ad300x250_container" >
        <div class="img-container scroll-touch" id="scrollbg">
          <img src="http://codeclippers.xyz/sprite.png" height="180px">
        </div>
        <div class="ad300x250_action" id="act">
            <button>INSTALL</button>
        </div>
        <div class="ad300x250_top ad_native_container" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <div class="ad300x250_icon"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/D2je9MPn25_t8JHv4HDCOJmWZ70IS1CyN4PkuXeyEFUJzyoP8kg1tp9Wn4EZLYvqdg=s180-rw">
            </div>
            <div class="ad300x250_title_container"> 
                <div class="ad300x250_title">
                    <span>Snack video</span>
                </div>
                    <div class="ad300x250_description"> 
                        <div class="ad300x250_description_text"></div>  
                        <div class="ad300x250_description_rating">4.6 &nbsp;&#9733;  FREE <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Google_Play_logo.png" style="
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 130px;
    top: 222px;
"/></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also have implemented scenario when mouse wheel goes up or down it will scroll horizontal image accordingly

Some how i can not replicate same in touch device

Here is js code of wheel event

```
const target = document.querySelector('#scrollbg');

    target.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
      const toLeft  = event.deltaY < 0 && target.scrollLeft > 0
      const toRight = event.deltaY > 0 && target.scrollLeft < target.scrollWidth - target.clientWidth
      console.log(toLeft)
      if (toLeft || toRight) {
        event.preventDefault()
        target.scrollLeft += event.deltaY
        //console.log(event.deltaY)
      }
    })
```

I would like to implement same functionality using javascript without jquery whenever user swipe on mobile devices image will adjust accordingly

Here is working demo of wheel event: https://jsfiddle.net/janakprajapati90/6cLau845/

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine in Chrome for Android. Is there a specific browser or device the issue occurs on?

Comment: I am testing it on MoPub SDK. yes it is working on chrome but its not working in mopub sdk